# IIS 6 httpmodule not being called when a path is given without extension

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, redirect, httpmodule

I want to implement a simple 404 redirector in asp.net hosted on iis6 on windows 2003

I have created a httpmodule and properly registered it in web.config. The redirection works perfectly when I use the "development server" (ctrl + F5) on VS 2005. The redirection works for these two scenarios:

1. When an extension is provided for a non-existent page (www.example.com/page2.htm)
2. When an extension is NOT provided (www.example.com/abc)

However, when I host the same application on IIS6, scenario (1) works as it is - but it is not able to process when it encounters scenario (2)

I tried adding a wildcard script mapping but that is of no help - I get a 404 error message given by the IIS..

How to deal with this - some setting in web.config or IIS?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

In IIS6 you can configure the 404 document to load.  See http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/80cb8d8d-8fd8-4af5-bb3b-4d11fff3ab9c.mspx?mfr=true

I don't think you'll be able to use your web.config file to load your 404 page in IIS6 mode, because ASP.NET isn't integrated into it (and thus doesn't even load).